# Cannot run Chromium as another user from the command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, chromium

Chrome is available from the command line:

```
$ chromium --version
Chromium 108.0.5359.124 snap
```

But not for other users:

```
$ sudo su otherphil
$ chromium --version
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

In addition, in the error message above, `1000` is the id of `philippe` (the user who can use Chrome), not `otherphil` (the user trying to use Chrome).

Actually I can reproduce this issue on a fresh Ubuntu Server 22:

```
$ sudo apt install chromium-browser
(...)
$ chromium --version
Chromium 108.0.5359.124 snap
$ sudo adduser otherphil
(...)
$ sudo su otherphil
$ chromium --version
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

How can I make Chrome available for all users?

Comment: Might be related with https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1951491

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how sessions are managed. Login as `otherphil` directly through SSH works (instead of connecting as `philippe`, than `sudo su otherphil`) does the trick.

What works:

```
$ ssh philippe@myserver
$ chromium --version # Works
```

What doesn't work:

```
$ ssh otheruser@myserver
$ sudo su philippe
$ chromium --version # Error!
```

Originally answered here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/not-a-snap-cgroup-error-when-running-chromium/33243/3?u=pbernard